# create jabber id on public XMPP servers

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I have shared hosting running apache. I want to integrate XMPP based chat on my live server. As for as my localhost it is working very fine with OpenFire.
Now I want to put it on live. My web application is a social networking app. On googling I learned about public XMPP servers, but to use those servers I need to create Jabber I using their form. Since in my requirement is to create Jabber id/user when someone registers on my website. 
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mass create account on public XMPP server as usually they provide the service to individual and use captcha to prevent bot registration.

If you want to provide a service on top of XMPP, you will need to deploy your own server.